# Stop a Jquery code when screen size goes under the certain width

Tags: jquery

This is jquery for the fixed element to stop right above the footer.

I want this jquery to stop for mobile (<720).
please help!

```js
$(window).scroll(() => { 
  // Distance from top of document to top of footer.
  topOfFooter = $('#shopify-section-product-recommendations').position().top;
  // Distance user has scrolled from top, adjusted to take in height of sidebar (570 pixels inc. padding).
  scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc = $(document).scrollTop() + 800;
  // Difference between the two.
  scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter = scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc - topOfFooter;

  // If user has scrolled further than footer,
  // pull sidebar up using a negative margin.

  if (scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc > topOfFooter) {
    $('.product-menu').css('margin-top',  0 - scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter);
  } else  {
    $('.product-menu').css('margin-top', 0);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the execution of the script when window is below a certain width

```
const stopBelow = 720;

$(window).scroll(() => {
  if (window.innerWidth < stopBelow) return;

  // Distance from top of document to top of footer.
  topOfFooter = $('#shopify-section-product-recommendations').position().top;
  // Distance user has scrolled from top, adjusted to take in height of sidebar (570 pixels inc. padding).
  scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc = $(document).scrollTop() + 800;
  // Difference between the two.
  scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter = scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc - topOfFooter;

  // If user has scrolled further than footer,
  // pull sidebar up using a negative margin.
  if ($(window).width() < 750) {
    $('.product-menu').css('margin-top', 0);
  }

  if (scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc > topOfFooter) {
    $('.product-menu').css('margin-top',  0 - scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter);
  } else  {
    $('.product-menu').css('margin-top', 0);
  }

});
```